# Convert hex value to filter attribute

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, gulp

I did find this on [codepen](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/KbvJow), but it uses `JS` to calculate the `filter` value manually. I want to be able to do this using `SASS` so that I can build these more programmatically.

Below is an example of the end results, but it requires me to hard code. We are using [gulpjs](https://gulpjs.com/) to compile our `SASS` files.

How would I be able to do what the `codepen` does, but with `SASS`?

```css
.icon {
  background-image: url('https://kwiksher.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/runningcat.png');
  display: block;
}

.icon--single {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-position: 25% 50%;
 filter: invert(46%) sepia(36%) saturate(6980%) hue-rotate(159deg) brightness(94%) contrast(101%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Hello there</h2>
  <span class="icon icon--single">hi</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would start

1. Look at the color [functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html) provided by Sass
2. Implement the missing [math functions](https://github.com/xi/sass-planifolia/tree/master/sass) (cos, sin etc.)
3. Start converting JS to Sass to see what else is needed

I would like to have posted the functions but it is not a trivial task (it can be done) and it's 2.08AM and I need sleep – let's call it round one ;)

Meanwhile give it a try and update your question with what you got working and not

Answer (score 1):

If you relax the original question's requirement that it be a pure CSS solution - you can set a color directly using a SVG Filter and reference that filter from CSS. The fifth column of a feColorMatrix matrix can be used to set RGB explicitly.